# Trying to remove "character-design" tag, but can't remove the last association

Tags: support, specific-tag

[This is the list of questions using the character-design tag](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-design)

Originally there were 10 questions associated with the [character-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-design) tag.  I believed that character design is intrinsically not worldbuilding and with so few questions attached, I began to remove that tag and, where possible, attach a tag that made more sense (like [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design)).

However, I can't remove the tag from one question on the list.  [This one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/37288/disscribing-something-ive-never-been-through), which has been migrated to Writing.SE.

With the automation take care of this (the automatic garbage collection), or must something be done to remove the WB.SE tag from what is now a W.SE question?

Answer (score 2):

The automatic cleanup of migration stubs will get it in a couple weeks.  I considered just deleting it now since it's destined to be deleted anyway, but the OP hasn't yet created an account on Writing, where the question was migrated, so I want to leave the breadcrumb here a little longer.